# Google Analytics for Android is not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I am developing an Android app. I am trying to integrate Google Analytics with my Android app. I am tracking page visited of my application. But data is not sent from app to Google Analytics Console/Dashboard. Here is what I have done:

1. I have already integrated Firebase Push Notification to my app. So I no need to add json file.
2. I registered my app from Firebase to Google Analytics and I got a Unique Track ID.
3. Then in my application class, I created tracker instance like this.

```
public class MApplication extends Application {

        public static final String GOOGLE_TRACK_ID ="MY-TRACK-ID";
        public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
        public static Tracker tracker;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
            tracker = analytics.newTracker(GOOGLE_TRACK_ID);
            tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
            tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
            tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
        }

    }
```

I initiate tracker like this because I cannot find XML file. So I found this solution - [Android Google Analytics xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233277/android-google-analytics-xml-file). This is why I instantiate like that.

4. Then in the page I want to track, I send data like this.

```
mApplication.tracker.setScreenName("Articles Page");
                mApplication.tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.football.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.football.waiyanhein.model.MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name="com.football.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.StartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        //Other activities go here

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1864111377153297"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <receiver android:name="com.football.waiyanhein.receiver.NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.receiver.NotificationReceiver"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.football.waiyanhein.receiver.MemeCreateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.receiver.MemeCreateReceiver"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service android:name="com.football.waiyanhein.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.football.waiyanhein.service.FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

No data is sent as you can see here.

[image]

When I check Analytics Dashboard, there is no user data, there is nothing sent in Analytics Dashboard. Why it is not working?

Comment: please note that your dashboard will update in next 24hrs. If you want to check real time analytics go to Realtime tab in google analytics console.

Comment: I check the real-time. Active users is still zero. :( . Is the way I am doing Right?

Comment: pls post your manifest

Comment: Yes I just updated the question.

Comment: Add analytics classes in your manifest. I have posted answer.

Comment: I tried using your way. But still not working. @NitinKarande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make sure your tracking id is a valid one.

```
public class MApplication extends Application {

        public static final String GOOGLE_TRACK_ID ="MY-TRACK-ID";
        public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
        public static Tracker tracker;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            getDefaultTracker();

        }

synchronized public void getDefaultTracker() {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
            tracker = analytics.newTracker(GOOGLE_TRACK_ID);
            tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
            tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
            tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

    }
```

Comment: This is working actually. The problem is with my track ID. There is an extra zero at the end. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below Code snippest for Google analytics

Add your **build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
 }
```

Add Java class **AnalyticsTrackers.java**

```
package com.nitin.tracker;

import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public final class AnalyticsTrackers {

 public enum Target {
    APP,
    // Add more trackers here if you need, and update the code in #get(Target) below
 }

private static AnalyticsTrackers sInstance;

public static synchronized void initialize(Context context) {
    if (sInstance != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Extra call to initialize analytics trackers");
    }

    sInstance = new AnalyticsTrackers(context);
}

public static synchronized AnalyticsTrackers getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Call initialize() before getInstance()");
    }

    return sInstance;
}

private final Map<Target, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<Target, Tracker>();
private final Context mContext;

/**
 * Don't instantiate directly - use {@link #getInstance()} instead.
 */
private AnalyticsTrackers(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}

public synchronized Tracker get(Target target) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(target)) {
        Tracker tracker;
        switch (target) {
            case APP:
                tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled analytics target " + target);
        }
        mTrackers.put(target, tracker);
    }

    return mTrackers.get(target);
}
}
```

Add **res/xml/app_tracker.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <!-- End current session if app sleeps for a period of time -->
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

<!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!--  The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-12345678-2</string>

<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Create extend Application class like **MyApplication .java**

```
package com.nitin.tracker;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;  
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.StandardExceptionParser;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
        .getSimpleName();

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;

    AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
    AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
    AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
    return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}


public void trackScreenView(String screenName) {

        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();
        // Set screen name.
        t.setScreenName(screenName);
        // Send a screen view.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();

}

public void trackException(Exception e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                .setDescription(
                        new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                .setFatal(false)
                .build()
        );
    }
}


public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
    Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

    // Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
}
}
```

Add **manifeast.xml**

```
<application
    android:name="com.nitin.tracker.MyApplication">
  <!-- Analytics Permission -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!--
         Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
         installation campaign reporting
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

If you want to track screen  Call

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().trackScreenView("Screen Name");
}
```

If you want to track Event

```
 MyApplication.getInstance().trackEvent("Module", "Event Name", "Operation of event");
```

Its work for me. Also I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Its working for me. Check your trckerId.. for more https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Ah yeah. I really sorry to all. The problem is with my track ID. There is an extra 0 at the end at my track ID. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding the below line of code in your activities needed to be tracked instead of the tracker.send() used.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I am doing this in Fragment. Besides, I need to name the page name checking conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For me the filename was wrong.

GTM container file name should be

```
GTM-<Container>.json
```

Mine was

```
GTM-<Container>_v2.json.
```

So, it was getting rejected by GTM engine. It was throwing an error.

*Ignoring container asset GTM-WKKQ37N_v2.json (does not match (gtm-[a-z0-9]{1,10}).json)*